# Uniform Continuity: $(\ln x)^2$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Determine if $f(x)=(\ln x)^2$ is uniformly continuous on $(0,\infty)$. I think I need to use the definition on this one. im not sure how tho, so any tips/solutions? $|y-x|< \delta$ => $|f(y)-f(x)|< \epsilon$

Comment: I am mistaken, please pay no attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not, because the function goes to infinity at zero. Pick $\epsilon=1$; if there were a $\delta$ such that $|x-y|<\delta\to|f(x)-f(y)|<1$ for every $x,y\in(0,\infty)$, we could pick $y=\delta$ and let $x$ go to $0$; for each such pair $|x-y|<\delta$ but $f(x)\to\infty$ and $f(y)=f(\delta)$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1):

$(\ln x)^2 -(\ln y)^2 = (\ln x + \ln y)(\ln x -\ln y)=\ln (xy) \ln (x/y)$

Fix an arbitrary $\delta >0$, put $x=2\eta$, $y=\eta$, where $\eta \in (0,\delta)$. Clearly $|x-y|=\eta<\delta$. Note that:

$|(\ln x)^2 -(\ln y)^2|=|\ln (xy) \ln (x/y)|=|\ln(2{\eta}^2)\ln 2|$

Since $\lim_{x \to 0} \ln x = -\infty$ it follows that $|\ln(2{\eta}^2)\ln 2|$ can be made arbitrarily large for sufficiently small $\eta >0$.

Hence $(\ln x)^2$ is not uniformly continuous in $(0,+\infty)$